# websocket request shown runs successfully on jmeter but in server shown error and Even in summery report report max time shown 0 for all requests

Tags: jmeter

websocket request shown runs successfully on jmeter but in server shown error and Even in summery report report max time shown 0 for all requests. Could you please help to improve the jmx script. please refer attached jmx script and document.

[Summery report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJzty.png)

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TbwatJR7AiiL09JU1RGl5BPQIj1sj8IG/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

`Could you please help to improve the jmx script` - no, we're not supposed to do your job for you, if this is what you're looking for - consider freelancers services like [Fiverr](https://www.fiverr.com/) or [Toptal](https://www.toptal.com/) however I can give you some idea regarding what could be wrong.

If connect time, latency and elapsed time are `0` then your requests are not very "successful", up to certain extent they are, but my expectation is that if you [enable debug logging for WebSocket Samplers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) component you will see each Sampler returning [101 Switching Protocols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/101) and I believe this is not something you expect from your WebSocket Samplers.

Given you're capable of successfully executing your scenario in browser you can capture the requests which are being sent by JMeter and the real browser using a 3rd-party sniffer tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) or [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and compare them. The requests must be exactly the same (apart from dynamic values which need to be [correlated](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)), once you amend your JMeter configuration to send the same requests as browser does your test will start working.